# How to install and use eth-auth (ethauth-server) library

Tags: node.js, authentication, npm, ethereum

First of all, what is **eth-auth** library and its usage? Also, How to install it (*ethauth-server npm library*) on my node.js project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**eth-auth** (*ethauth-server*) is a secure **npm library** for password-less user authentication for node.js decentralized applications (dApps) by signing an outwardly unpredictable dynamic JWT token with the user's Ethereum private key.

[image: Architecture]

**Highlights**

> 1. Decentralised (Web3)
> 2. Anonymous - User identity covered to dApp governors and the rest of the world.
> 3. Password-less - Your Ethereum private key is your password, and it won't reveal to anyone.
> 4. Breach-less - According to the eth-auth authentication architecture, no need to store meaningful user data in a database.

✅ **Installation**
Add eth-auth as a dependency to your project.

*npm:*

```
npm install ethauth-server
```

*yarn*

```
yarn add ethauth-server
```

Documentation: https://sathnindu-kottage.gitbook.io/eth-auth/

GitHub: https://github.com/project-evilcodes/ethauth-server

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethauth-server

Web: https://eth-auth-beta.netlify.app

Answer (score 0):

Just like installing other npm packages,

```
npm install ethauth-server
```

And import the package

More details: https://sathnindu-kottage.gitbook.io/eth-auth/